# Python/Tkinter Label can't be seen

Tags: python, tkinter, label, accelerometer

I use accelerometer device and I can see results on my screen. E.g:left,right...etc. However, I can't see these results on my tkinter table as I designed.

```
    import Tkinter as tk   // tkinter
    from liblo import *
    import sys
    import time
    import math

    # Other global variables

    stopAllThreads = False
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("ARAC TAKIP EKRANI")  //*my table name*//


    lblpay = tk.Label(bg='black', fg='yellow', width=30)

    lblpay.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=2)
```

I want to show print messages on my labels. However I can't.

```
    if(args[0] == 1):
            print ('ACIL DURUM FRENI\n')
            lblpay = tk.Label(text="ACIL DURUM FRENI")
            elif self.alpha/4 > 0.20:
                print ('ILERI\n') + str(self.alpha/4)
            lblpay = tk.Label(text="ILERI")
        elif self.z > 200:
                print ('SAG\n')
            lblpay = tk.Label(text="SAG")
        elif self.z < -200 :
                print ('SOL\n')
            lblpay = tk.Label(text="SOL")
        elif self.x < -200:
            print ('GERI\n') 
            lblpay = tk.Label(text="GERI")
        else:
                print ('PARK HALINDE\n')
            lblpay = tk.Label(text="PARK HALINDE")
```

Comment: Can you post whole code?

Comment: i ve a problem with Label.we dont need whole code.

Comment: Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) then, or it's a complete guessing game what you mean by "show print messages on my labels"

Comment: @Nae: we definitely don't want "whole code". What we do need, however, is a [mcve].

Comment: Ok i get it.Next time i Will be carefull

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change an option in a widget object you could use:

```
lblpay.configure(text="ILERI")
```

or if you want to create all over again you need to call geometry manager function(s) again after creation like:

```
...
else:
        print ('PARK HALINDE\n')
    lblpay = tk.Label(text="PARK HALINDE")

lblpay.grid()
```

as in your 'relative' code pieces should look either, and for the better, like:

```
if(args[0] == 1):
        print ('ACIL DURUM FRENI\n')
        lblpay.configure(text="ACIL DURUM FRENI")
        elif self.alpha/4 > 0.20:
            print ('ILERI\n') + str(self.alpha/4)
        lblpay.configure(text="ILERI")
    elif self.z > 200:
            print ('SAG\n')
        lblpay.configure(text="SAG")
    elif self.z < -200 :
            print ('SOL\n')
        lblpay.configure(text="SOL")
    elif self.x < -200:
        print ('GERI\n') 
        lblpay.configure(text="GERI")
    else:
            print ('PARK HALINDE\n')
        lblpay.configure(text="PARK HALINDE")
```

or like:

```
if(args[0] == 1):
        print ('ACIL DURUM FRENI\n')
        lblpay = tk.Label(text="ACIL DURUM FRENI")
        elif self.alpha/4 > 0.20:
            print ('ILERI\n') + str(self.alpha/4)
        lblpay = tk.Label(text="ILERI")
    elif self.z > 200:
            print ('SAG\n')
        lblpay = tk.Label(text="SAG")
    elif self.z < -200 :
            print ('SOL\n')
        lblpay = tk.Label(text="SOL")
    elif self.x < -200:
        print ('GERI\n') 
        lblpay = tk.Label(text="GERI")
    else:
            print ('PARK HALINDE\n')
        lblpay = tk.Label(text="PARK HALINDE")

    lblpay.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=2)
```

Comment: Thanks nae i Will try " Label.configure"  .Because,i ve options like:left,right,bottom and up..i guess ".configure" solve my problem.